# simple script for generating archives arj

Tags: c#, arj

here's code:

```
string command = string.Empty;
DirectoryInfo dInfoForTesting = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\TestFiles");
FileInfo[] files = dInfoForTesting.GetFiles();
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    string rndPswd = "134";
    command = "arj a -m1 -g" + rndPswd + " " + file.Name + ".arj " + file.FullName;
    Process.Start(@"C:\ARJ_TEST\programming\test\ARJ.EXE", command);
}
```

I want to create automatically archives protected by simple password **134** uisng ARJ archiver. But when i run this code for the first file i see the image below. But this file exists!

Please, help to understand me, what i am doing wrong.

[image: the following lines in cmd]

**EDIT**:

i 've decided to rewrite code to run cmd in the folder `E:\TestFiles`, where there are all files for testing:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                WorkingDirectory = @"E:\TestFiles",
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardInput = false
            };
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        string rndPswd = "134";
        command = "arj a -m1 -g" + rndPswd + " " + file.Name + ".arj " + file.Name;
        startInfo.Arguments = command;
        Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
```

For example, if i run command `arj a -m1 -g134 10.arj 10` directly from cmd, arj creates an archive `10.arj`. But when i run my code for the first file (`10`) nothing happens...

Comment: What is `file.FullName` for one of the files?  Does it contain any spaces?

Comment: @Amy, for example, in VS12 i see `E:\\TestFiles\\10`

Comment: The file is called `10`?

Comment: yes, without extension.

Comment: Okay, what is the exact content of `command`?

Comment: `a -m1 -g134 10.arj E:\\TestFiles\\10` (in VS12)

Comment: Nothing really jumps out at me, sorry.

Comment: What happen when you try it directly in the command prompt ?

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa, the same thinq, path to arj.exe added to PATH variable